# Construct a Trigonal Trapezahedron from another platonic solid

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Looking into the Tetartoid, which is a version of the Dodecahedron where all pentagons are not regular, described in the answer by Aretino [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393370/what-are-the-rules-for-a-tetartoid-pentagon) is a way to construct it from a Tetrahedron.

Similarly, the asymmetric version of a [Trigonal Trapezohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_trapezohedron) is a relaxation of the conditions of a cube where the faces don't have to be regular (only two adjacent ones need to be). I feel there must be a way to similarly construct it from a platonic solid as well.

Also, Aretino links to [this](http://loki3.com/poly/transforms.html) page where the construction of the Tetartoid is described. And in the section "4t", there does appear to be a solid that "looks like" the Trigonal Trapezahedron. But I can't be sure if it's even convex.

So my question is, does a corresponding construction exist for the asymmetric version of the Trigonal Trapezahedron from a Platonic solid?

Comment: I think this answer to another question could be of interest to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144830/hexahedron-congruent-faces/2146367#2146367